# MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `floor(var int)'

Tags: minizinc

I'm trying to run the following code on Mac OS/X with Minizinc IDE 2.2.3 and Geocode 6.1.0 [built in]:

```
var 1..10: x;
var float: y = x div 4;

constraint y == floor(y);

solve minimize( (x - 7)^2 );

output ["\(x) \(y)"]
```

The error I receive is:

> MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `floor(var float)'

I've seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406318/in-minizinc-how-can-i-resolve-this-error), however, I'm following the advice in the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415154/1033422) and using:

- float decision variable
- geocode solver

Thus, this question is different from the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation (v. 2.2.3)](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.3/en/spec.html) says that `floor()` requires an argument of type `float`:

> **4.1.11.6. Coercion Operations**
>
> Round a float towards +∞, −∞, and the nearest integer, respectively.
>
> ```
> int: ceil (float)
> int: floor(float)
> int: round(float)
> ```
>
> Explicit casts from one type-inst to another.
>
> ```
>     int:          bool2int(    bool)
> var int:          bool2int(var bool)
>     float:        int2float(    int)
> var float:        int2float(var int)
> array[int] of $T: set2array(set of $T)
> ```

In your model, you pass a `var float` instead of a `float` to the function `floor`, thus you get a **type error**.

---

Having said this, in your example the `floor()` function does not seem to be necessary. Even though you declare `y` to be a `var float`, this can only be assigned some *integral* value, because the result of the *integer division* is always an *integer*:

```
function var int: 'div'(var int: x, var int: y)
```

Thus, my suggestion is to drop `floor()` altogether.

**example**

```
var 1..10: x;
var float: y = x div 4;

constraint 1.5 <= y;

solve minimize( (x - 7)^2 );

output ["\(x) \(y)"]
```

yields

```
~$ minizinc t.mzn 
8 2.0
----------
==========
```